# Why does this user's picture keep changing?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-picture

One of the more active [users](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/6591/user6591) on one of my sites has an issue with his user-picture. Namely, it keeps changing on us, and it's ***really annoying***.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

I've [asked him about it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19679880#19679880), and [asked him if he'd changed his email recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19679898#19679898), and his [response](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19680179#19680179) was

> @Shokhet I have no idea! I thought i noticed something funny going on
> with the pics. You didn't believe me when I told you technology and i
> don't get along, did you? Now you believe me?

Can we ***please*** get this fixed? It's really annoying, as I use those profile pictures to help me quickly identify who posted what, and 6591 is one of the really good guys.

Answer (score 8):

He doesn't have an email address on his profile, nor has he uploaded an image to use as an avatar. Therefore, his image is generated based on the IP address he was last seen from. When that changes, so does his picture...

Comment: I let him know about your answer, thanks! // Just curious, why is this post CW?

Comment: @Shokhet Guess because he essentially posted same answer as in the dupe. (note the time of making it CW - right after closing as dupe)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, I see....I thought the answer was CW to begin with. Interesting....

Comment: @Shokhet it's visible in the revisions, most likely Shog posted the answer and only then found the dupe.

Comment: I see, @ShadowWizard. I checked the revisions before responding to you ;-) ....I was actually wondering why post an answer to a duplicate question; your theory explains that also :)